# Trying to exclude custom posts based on date, while sorting by custom field

Tags: posts, customization, filters, query

I have a custom post type named "performance". I have a custom post query that orders posts by a custom field value (order-date). Now I want to exclude posts that have order-dates that are in the past. I would think I could use the same "order-date" value to compare against todays date to determine if a post should be shown, but I can't find an example that works with the ordering. Everything I've tried breaks the ordering.

This seems to work!

```
<?php
  $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $today = date('Y-m-d');
  query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'performance', 
    'posts_per_page' => 5, 
    'caller_get_posts' => 5, 
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_key' => 'order-date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'order-date',
        'meta-value' => $value,
        'value' => $today,
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type' => 'CHAR'
        )
      )
    ));
if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
```

Note that I defined "$today" and added it to the meta_array for comparison with the meta-value. The past-dated performance items disappeared from the list and everything looks like it should. Thanks to Brady for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of `meta_query` http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

```
<?php
 $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
 query_posts(array(
 'post_type' => 'performance', 
 'posts_per_page' => 5, 
 'caller_get_posts' => 5, 
 'paged' => $paged,
 'meta_key' => 'order-date',
 'orderby' => 'meta_value',
 'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'order-date',
            'value' => $value,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'CHAR'
        )
    )
 ));
if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
```

Comment: Brady - Thanks, but I'm not sure how to implement this. I'm getting an error.

Comment: Here is the code I implemented:
    <?php
     $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
     $args = array(
     'post_type' => 'performance',
     'meta_query' => array(
     array(
     'key' => 'order-date',
     'value' => $value,
     'compare' => '>='
    ),
 array(
 'posts_per_page' => 5, 
 'caller_get_posts' => 5, 
 'paged' => $paged,
 'meta_key' => 'order-date',
 'orderby' => 'meta_value',
 'order' => 'ASC'
 ),
 )
 );
 $query = new WP_Query( $args );
 if (have_posts()) :
 while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    ?>

Comment: Can't get the code to display correctly; sorry.

Comment: firstly what error are you getting. secondly please update your question with the code your trying. thirdly how are you storing your date, what format?

Comment: <?php $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
   $args = array( 
   'meta_query' => array( 
      array( 
        'key' => 'order-date', 
        'value' => $value, 
        'compare' => '>=' ), 
      array( 
        'post_type' => 'performance', 
        'posts_per_page' => 5, 
        'caller_get_posts' => 5, 
        'paged' => $paged, 
        'meta_key' => 'order-date', 
        'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
        'order' => 'ASC' )
      ) ); 
    $query = new WP_Query( $args ); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    ?>

Comment: Code is above. Cannot get it to display correctly in comment box (using 4 spaces). Custom field value is in Y-m-d format. Rather than an error message, it simply displays blog posts instead of custom posts.

Comment: Dont post code in the comment box it wont work. Instead edit your original question and put it there. Secondly the code I gave you was to add to what you already had not to replace it. Thirdly because you are using Y-m-d format you will have to set the query type to CHAR and not DATE as I gave you originally.

Comment: Thanks, Brady. The code above does not break anything, and it doesn't disturb my sort, and it displays the custom posts. But it does not filter out past events: still lists all performance custom posts.

Comment: Brady - The code you gave me was very close, and I'm accepting it as the answer; just had to make a minor adjustment. See original question for updated code.